# How to find a tr which has a specific class attached and get the details of each td - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please check out this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/y7jqb5hp/7/

```js
function getdetails(row) {
  $("#tableID tbody tr").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("highlightRowSelected");
  });
  $(row).addClass("highlightRowSelected");
}

function DetailsOfTheSelectedRows() {
  $.each($("#tableID tbody tr.highlightRowSelected"), function() {
    $('#txtBoxValue').value = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.highlightRowSelected {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <th>checkbox</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Alfreds </td>
    <td>Maria </td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Centro </td>
    <td>Francisco </td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Ernst </td>
    <td>Roland </td>
    <td>Austria</td>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="DetailsOfTheSelectedRows()" value="Selected Row" />

<input type="text" id="txtBoxValue" />
```

in actual project whole tbody is dynamic , so dont change Html and `getdetails(row)` function

Table rows can have multiple class added to them dynamically  .

My job is to get only that row which has that `highlightRowSelected` attached to it , get the first columns value and show it in text box

Jquery function `DetailsOfTheSelectedRows` has to be dynamic too so selector should be there and only one row will have that class name attached .

so how to write `DetailsOfTheSelectedRows` :

Comment: use that class to find that tr like `$('tr.classname')`

Comment: $('#txtBoxValue').value= $('tr.highlightRowSelected').find('td:eq(2)').text(); tried like this , didnt work

Comment: `$("#txtBoxValue").val($("#tableID tr.highlightRowSelected > td:first").text())`

Comment: Is this what you want, kinda confused https://jsfiddle.net/6s0cxtfq/

Comment: First column would be `.find("td:eq(0)")`.   Make sure you can get the value first by alerting the part of the right of the equals first.

Comment: not working .tried last one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code as

```
function DetailsOfTheSelectedRows()
{
 $.each($(".highlightRowSelected",'#tableID'), function () {

       $('#txtBoxValue').val($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());

    });

}
```

Updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/y7jqb5hp/9/

Check it

Answer (score 1):

One-liner inside your DetailsOfTheSelectedRows() function...

```
function DetailsOfTheSelectedRows() {
  $('#txtBoxValue').val($('#tableID tr.highlightRowSelected td:eq(1)').text())
}
```

Here's your fiddle, updated: https://jsfiddle.net/9cuoe5df/